# PyQGIS feature field of type float not setting attribute

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am trying to set a feature in a PyQGIS processing script

Its fields are defined like so:

```py
interp_fields=QgsFields()
        interp_fields.append(QgsField('X_int', type=QVariant.Double))
        interp_fields.append(QgsField('Y_int', type=QVariant.Double))
        interp_fields.append(QgsField('Z_int', type=QVariant.Double))
```

The sink I am pushing the feature into looks like this:

```
(interp_sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT_INTERP,
            context,
            interp_fields,
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
```

My value I am trying to set is from a pandas dataframe "new"
and I am iterating over an array that has the same count of rows

```
for counter, interp_z in enumerate(interp_sampled_values):
            #just to see if we actually got a value

            feedback.pushInfo(str(new["X_int"][counter]))
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break
            #make new feature
            new_feat = QgsFeature()
            #set its fields
            new_feat.setFields(interp_fields)
            #create geometry from point 
            interp_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(new["X_int"][counter],new["Y_int"][counter]))
            new_feat.setGeometry(interp_geometry)

                  
            
           
            # Add a feature in the sink
            new_feat.setAttribute('X_int',new["X_int"][counter])
                     
            
            #feedback.pushInfo(new_feat.attributes)
            interp_sink.addFeature(new_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
```

I KNOW that `new["X_int"][counter]` is delivering a float64 value. Geometry is just fine.
I am getting the error message
`Could not store attribute "X_int": Could not convert value "" to target type "double"`

I know however, that it should work formally, as I can give it a constant like
`new_feat.setAttribute('X_int',1)`

And it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

It seems to be some type conversion issue.

Comment: Try adding a specific type function around it?

Comment: I tried that.
"converting" it with ```new_feat.setAttribute('X_int',int(new["X_int"][counter]))``` works. But there I am losing precision. 
I need double. However, it doesn't accept floats for the double type

Comment: Just using float() did the job.

Which is weird, because the pandas dtypte of the values is float64 as well

Comment: I'd expect storing an `int` in a `float` to fail -

Comment: Pandas `float64` and Python `float` are not the same, which is why casting one to the other works.

Comment: @Terranigmus: Consider adding the solution as an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the pandas float to a standard python float was the solution

`new_feat.setAttribute('X_int',float(new["X_int"][counter]))`

Even though their dtype is the same, they are not.